# Assigned text to label doesn't get updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

So this is my function which serves an AJAX call:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button1.Text = "surprise";
            Label1.Text = "surprise!!";
            Label2.Text = "surprise!!";
        }
```

This is the `aspx`. Scriptmanager is set.

```
    <p>Síðast slóstu inn:
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </p>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">asd</asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">dsa</asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You can see for yourselves if you want: http://webapplication44730.azurewebsites.net/data

As you can see, the button text changes to "surprise" but the labels, `Label1` and `Label2` which should appear after 'inn,' don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause it that those labels are not inside the `UpdatePanel`, which means they will not get updated from the AJAX callback.

Set the update panel around every control you need to update:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <p>Síðast slóstu inn:
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">asd</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">dsa</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Oh gosh, thank you. Sorry that this was such a clumsy error, I'm new to ASP.net.